# Fixed Header FadeOut, FadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm a noob when it comes to JS, so I apologise in advance.

I'm trying to make a fixed header, that 'fades to' 0.5 Opacity when scrolled down and fades back to full opaqueness ('opacity': 1.0) when scrolled back to the top?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var div = $('#header');
var start = $(div).offset().top;

$.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
if($(window).scrollTop();
$('#header').fadeTo(600, 0.5);

$(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
$(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '0px');

});
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question ?

Comment: What is it doing so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body, html').on('scroll', function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
         $("#header").fadeTo(600, 0.5);
     }else{
         $("#header").fadeTo(600, 1);

     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @adeneo but if I implement this code, my header is no longer fixed and it no longer scrolls with the page?

Comment: That's because you have positioned it wrong, if you'd like it to scroll, use position absolute or relative, if you like it to stay put, use fixed.

Comment: @Self_Taught_Programmer I've positioned my #header in css as 'fixed' but this still doesn't seem to work. It fades to 0.5 opacity when you scroll but it doesn't go back to full opaqueness when I scroll back up.

Here's what I have now:

    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0){
    $("#header").fadeTo(200, 1);
    }else{
    $("#header").fadeTo(600, 0.5);
    }
    });

Comment: See my edited answer. If you have some margin/padding that could effect the top position etc. try adjusting the value of when it starts the fading.